# Shor's algorithm effectiveness

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm

In Shor's algorithm we require the period to be even. If the period is not even or $x^{r/2}+1 \equiv 0 \bmod N$ then we have to restart the process and pick a new random $x$. Why do we know that the process will work for some $x$ and still be quicker than the current method of just checking if factors work?

(Here $r$ is the period, $x$ is the random number given at the start of Shor's, $N$ is the number to be factorised.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out Thoerem 5.3 in Nielsen and Chuang. It conveys that we are almost guaranteed to get a good value of $x$ (the probability is stated to be at least $1-\frac{1}{2^m}$ where there are $m$ unique prime factors of $N$). The expected number of repetitions of the algorithm (due to this effect) is only just more than 1. At worst, it's 2. There's no absolute guarantee that in a particular instance you wouldn't need many, many repetitions, it's just ridiculously unlikely.

Comment: Would you by chance know where to find a proof of this theorem? There doesn't appear to be one in the book.

Comment: @paulinho Appendix 4, section A4.3 of Nielsen & Chuang.